# how can we add two String arraylist in hashmap and retrive value as match with key name index

Tags: java, selenium

I want to add two string type arraylist in hashmap and retrive its value depend upon key value ,So how can i do it ? My code is given below.I am trying to handle 
dynamic web table in selenuim in which column position is changes for different client.

```
public class Abcd
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{  

      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
      String baseUrl = "";
      driver.get(baseUrl);

      driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
      driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("Pass@123");
      String captcha; 
      Scanner src=new Scanner(System.in); 
      captcha=src.next();
      driver.findElement(By.id("txtImage")).sendKeys(captcha);

      driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click(); 
      Thread.sleep(20000);


      ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
      ArrayList al1=new ArrayList();

      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'#bottomuppanel')]")).click();
      Thread.sleep(5000);

      List<WebElement> SecuritySliceColHeader = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'dxpgColumnFieldValue_Metropolis dxpgColumnTotalFieldValue_Metropolis dxpgColumnGrandTotalFieldValue_Metropolis lastLevel')]"));
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      for (WebElement header : SecuritySliceColHeader) 
      {
        String ColHead=header.getText();
        al.add(ColHead);
        System.out.println("Col Header are:"+al);

      }
      Thread.sleep(2000);

      List<WebElement> grandHeader = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'lastVertCell dxpgCell_Metropolis dxpgGrandTotalCell_Metropolis')]"));
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      for(WebElement grand : grandHeader)
      {
          try
          {
          String grandTotalHeader=grand.getText();
          String grandTotalHeader_val=grandTotalHeader.substring(0, grandTotalHeader.length()-1);
          al1.add(grandTotalHeader_val);
          System.out.println("Grand Headers are "+al1);
          }catch(Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

      }
      HashMap<ArrayList, ArrayList> hmap = new HashMap<ArrayList, ArrayList>();
      hmap.put(al1, al);

    for(Map.Entry m:hmap.entrySet())
    {  
       System.out.println("Key :"+m.getKey()+"Value:"+m.getValue());  

    }  
 }
```

}

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Comment: what do you meant by "and retrive its value depend upon key value" . can you give an example

Comment: *I want to add two string type arraylist in hashmap and retrive its value depend upon key value ,So how can i do it* -> ????. Please edit your question and make it more clear what you actually want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you want to store first list items as keys and second list items as values in a `HashMap`. For that, you need to create a `hashmap` of `string, string` type as given below and store all its value there.

```
HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
for(int i=0;i<a1.size();i++){
  hmap.put(a1.get(i),a11.get(i));
}

for(Map.Entry m:hmap.entrySet())
{  
   System.out.println("Key :"+m.getKey()+"Value:"+m.getValue());  

}
```